# Cómo ordeno un diccionario en un orden específico respecto a sus claves?

Tags: python, pandas, diccionarios, ordenamiento

soy nuevo usando Python. Tengo un diccionario:
`diccionario = {'Abril': 207, 'Agosto': 227, 'Diciembre': 207, 'Enero': 218, 'Febrero': 230, 'Julio': 219, 'Junio': 208, 'Marzo': 230, 'Mayo': 201, 'Noviembre': 215, 'Octubre': 218, 'Septiembre': 215}`
el cual quiero ordenar en el orden de

```
mi_orden = ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"]
```

para poder graficar mes y conteo de manera ordenada (en cuanto a mes). Alguien podría ayudarme? ya busqué con los métodos sort() y la función sorted pero no logro hacerlo. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cómo haces la gráfica? Porque a lo mejor en lugar de ordenar el diccionario (cosa que no está soportada por todas las versiones de python) lo que tendrías que hacer es ordenar la forma en que lo pintas (quizás haya un parámetro de la función que hace la gráfica para ello)

Answer (score 1):

No se si esta será la manera más eficiente, pero algo muy fácil de implementar.

```
mi_orden = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", 
"Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"]
ordenado = {}
for value in mi_orden:
    ordenado[value] = diccionario[value]

print(ordenado) # {'Enero': 218, 'Febrero': 230, 'Marzo': 230, 'Abril': 207, ... }
```

Comment: **Muchas gracias!**

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que he leído, solo podrás ordenarlo si utilizas una versión de `python 3.7` en adelante:

Una manera de ordenarlo puede ser:

```
ordenado = {c: diccionario[c] for c in mi_orden}
print(ordenado)
```

Devuelve:

```
{'Enero': 218, 'Febrero': 230, 'Marzo': 230, 'Abril': 207, 'Mayo': 201, 'Junio': 208, 'Julio': 219, 'Agosto': 227, 'Septiembre': 215, 'Octubre': 218, 'Noviembre': 215, 'Diciembre': 207}
```

Si lo quieres es acceder al diccionario en un orden determinado (que esto puede ser lo que necesitas), ya que tienes la lista `mi_orden` y una lista si que tiene orden, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
for n in mi_orden:
    print(n,diccionario[n])
```

Verás que ahora accede a `diccionario` utilizando el orden de `mi_orden`.
Devolviendo:

```
Enero 218
Febrero 230
Marzo 230
Abril 207
Mayo 201
Junio 208
Julio 219
Agosto 227
Septiembre 215
Octubre 218
Noviembre 215
Diciembre 207
```

Comment: **Muchas gracias !**